# Ashx force download image

Tags: asp.net

I have an ashx file that display an image.
I would like not to display the image but force the download.

This is my code :

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + userId + ".jpg");
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(msMasterFinal.ToArray(), 0, msMasterFinal.ToArray().Length);
```

When I open my browser with this ashx, the image is
automatically displayed. How to force download please ?

Many thanks

Comment: Does that space between the semicolon and the filename= in your disposition header make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you code looks right. I've used this snippet in the past to achieve what you're trying to do:

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=""{0}""", FileName));
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", FileType);
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FileSize.ToString);
context.Response.BinaryWrite(FileBytes);
```

It's almost similar...

Comment: Thanks Jackob, but I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser always will show pictures in window if they contentType wiil be "image/jpeg". Try to use different contentType.